# CodeIgniter 404 not found controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I know the question has been asked many times but I really can't solve the issue.
My default controller is working, but if I want to access another controller I will have the 404 issue.

My controller file name has the upper case as Utilisateur.php,
So I'm trying to access the Controller function `inscription` by `<a href="Utilisateur/inscription">inscription</a>`

Here is my config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:63342/WeBusy/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Here is my rooting:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'accueil';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

And finally the controler:

```
class Utilisateur extends CI_Controller {

    public function inscription(){
        $data = array('header' => 'HeaderAccueil.php', 'body' => 'utilisateur/AjoutUtilForm.php');
        $this->load->view('StructureHtml.php', $data);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: in your function inscription() - remove everything and put in echo 'test';

Comment: then you can really see whether its the route or something else.

Comment: Done and I still have 404 error

Comment: Is `http://localhost:63342/WeBusy/index.php/utilisateur/inscription` this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issues,
So I needed to create a .htaccess file in the root of the applicaiton in order to remove the index.php AND this still doesn't work with phpstorm, maybe there is something to configure but it is working smoothly on EasyPhp :)

Answer (score 0):

Give complete path to your anchor

```
<a href="http://localhost:63342/WeBusy/Utilisateur/inscription">inscription</a>
```

But the best practice is to give dynamic url like using url helper or constants.

For Example if use url helper function your anchor path is like.

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>Utilisateur/inscription">inscription</a>
```

Don't forget to load url helper in your autoload file or your class constructor.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve anything considering that I already had the right path (http://localhost:63342/WeBusy/Utilisateur/inscription) when clicking the link.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your controller filename, should be **U**tilisateur.php (ucfirst).
2. Check if your mod_rewrite works:

   1. http://localhost:63342/WeBusy/index.php?q=utilisateur/inscription
   2. add new method index() {die('test');} to your Utilisateur controller and change $route['default_controller'] = 'accueil'; to: $route['default_controller'] = 'utilisateur';